# What this XPath expression match in an XSLT template rule? *|/

Tags: xslt, xpath

From my understanding of XSLT I can't figure out what does it match.

```
<xsl:template match="*|/">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath matching is relative to a 'current node' (i.e. current position) in the XML being matched.

`*` matches all child elements of the current node, whereas `/` matches the root - and only the root - regardless of what the current node is.

Note also that the root is NOT the root element of the XML, it is actually a level above it - the root element is a child of the root.

If you have this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/|*">
      <item name="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </item>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and you apply it to this XML:

```
<rootElement>
  <subElement1/>
  <subElement2/>
</rootElement>
```

you get this:

```
<item name="">
  <item name="rootElement">
    <item name="subElement1" />
    <item name="subElement2" />
  </item>
</item>
```

the first `<item name="">` correspond to the match of `/` (that is not an element, and so does not have a name), the others are the matches of `*`.

Comment: is there any sense to put another xsl:template element with the matcihng pattern "/" inside the same stylesheet?

Comment: @Bax unless one or other of the templates has a priority specified that would be an error as both templates would match / with the same priority.